# Obtain the last value from every sensor on my django model

Tags: django, django-models

I am working with Django and I am a bit lost on how to extract information from models (tables).

I have a table containing different information from various sensors. What I would like to know is if it is possible from the Django models to obtain for each sensor (each sensor has an identifier) ​​the last row of data (using the timestamp column).

In sql it would be something like this, (probably the query is not correct but I think you can understand what I'm trying)

```
SELECT sensorID,timestamp,sensorField1,sensorField2 
FROM sensorTable 
GROUP BY sensorID 
ORDER BY max(timestamp);
```

I have seen that the `group_by()` function exists and also `lastest()` but I don't get anything coherent and I'm also not clear if I'm choosing the best form.

Can anyone help me get started with this topic? I imagine it is very easy but it is a new world and it is difficult to start.

Greetings!

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: sorry, I'm using postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a *PostgreSQL* database, you can make use of the [**`.distinct(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) of the queryset where you add fields that determine on what these should be distinct.

So you can obtain the latest sensors in Django with:

```
SensorModel.objects.order_by('sensor', '-timestamp').distinct('sensor')
```

We thus order by `sensor` (which is required for a `.distinct(..)`), and then in case of a *tie* (so two times the same sensor), we order on the timestamp in descending order, hence we pick the latest `SensorModel` object for that sensor.

Comment: Hello! One question, with this code I obtain the last value of each sensor. But it is possible to obtain for example the last 3 values of every sensor with this? I tried adding `SensorModel.objects.order_by('sensor', '-timestamp').distinct('sensor')[:3]` but it's wrong. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @Lleims: no, this will give you the latest sensor info of the first three sensors. There is no easy trick for this I think. Likely Django currenly has no expressions for that, so you perhaps need to use the `RawSQL`.